# jquery click event on whole selection using "this" keyword

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say that you have an image gallery like so:

```
<div id="gallery">
<a href="images/one_sb.JPG"><img src="images/one_s.jpg" /></a>
<a href="images/two_sb.JPG"><img src="images/two_s.jpg" /></a>
<a href="images/three_sb.JPG"><img src="images/three_s.jpg" /></a>
<a href="images/four_sb.JPG"><img src="images/four_s.jpg" /></a>
<a href="images/five_sb.JPG"><img src="images/five_s.jpg" /></a>
<a href="images/six_sb.JPG"><img src="images/six_s.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

And you want to bind an event handler to each individual image. This event handler will be part of an image gallery mechanism that uses thumbnails to switch from small images to big images.

Some of the code:

```
$('#gallery a').click(function(evt) {
    //don't follow link
     evt.preventDefault();
     //get path to new image
   var imgPath = $(this).attr('href');
     //get reference to old image
     etc...

}); // end click
```

From my understanding the `$()` does: "[jQuery returns the elements in a collection](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/)" in essence it returns all the  tags that are children of the "gallery" id

If $() returns a collection than why does it seem like by using the "click" event handler that the collection is being iterated over and we can reference the current element being clicked on by "this"? Wouldn't we need to use the "each()" method to iterate over the jQuery object that was returned with `$('#gallery a')`

Any references to jQuery documentation in answer to this would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to look at this way - "If clicked element is within the given selector rules, apply these actions", yes - it could be a collection of jQuery elements, but of those *listening* for an action. If you wanted to apply `$.each()` on a `$(this)` within an click function, it would only iterate once anyway

Comment: jQuery does an each automatically. Also, with $("#id").on() (forgot syntax, im mobile) u can attach 1 handler (not 10) and then inside put selector to do ur functionality. Read it anyway ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### ***Implicit iteration***

With this invocation of the `$` function:

```
$('#gallery a')
```

...you're passing a selector string, and it returns all the matched `<a>` elements. Most of the jQuery methods will automatically iterate over the collection, and perform the expected task.

So this iterates the `<a>` elements, and assigns the handler to each one.

```
$('#gallery a').click(function(evt) {...
```

This is often called *implicit iteration*.

---

### ***Passing an element to the `$` function***

When the handler is finally invoked in response to a browser event, you're making a separate call to the `$` function, and this time, instead of a selector string, you're passing `this`, which happens to be set to the element that was clicked.

```
$(this).attr(...
```

So it still returns a collection, but there's only one element in the collection; the one you passed.

---

### ***How did `this` come to point to the right element?***

The way that `this` ends up pointing to the element that was clicked is that that is the default behavior of event handlers. So in the actual handler bound to the element, `this` is the value of the clicked element.

You can confirm this by binding a handler the old way.

```
document.body.onclick = function() {
    alert(this.tagName);
};
```

You'll see that `this` is the `body` element.

So what jQuery does  is that they manually set the `this` value they received to your handler when they invoke it. That way the behavior of the handler is consistent with the traditional way.

---

### ***Minor details***

Couple side notes, jQuery doesn't use `element.onclick =` to assign the handler. They use `element.addEventListener`. In old IE browsers that don't support `.addEventListener()`, they use `element.attachEvent`.

In `.attachEvent`, the `this` value does *not* point to the element clicked, so they need to implement some other trickery to make it work.

The handler you provided is never actually bound to the element. jQuery instead binds a generic proxy that receives all events for the element, stores your actual handler in `jQuery.cache`, and then looks up and invokes your handler when the event takes place.

Comment: Thanks @cookie monster. Very helpful. So you could say that this behavior is analogous to how closures work.

Comment: @robertrocha: No, that's an entirely separate concept. Functions in JavaScript keep a permanent reference to their original variable scope, even if the function is moved out of that scope. That's a closure.

Comment: here is the official documentation "jQuery provides simple methods for attaching event handlers to selections. When an event occurs, the provided function is executed. Inside the function, this refers to the element that was clicked."  http://learn.jquery.com/events/

Answer (score -1):

`this` within an event handler refers only to the element that the event is registered with, not the whole collection that matched your query.

```
var links = $('#gallery a').click(function(evt) {
   // this here is only the link that was clicked, 
   // not all the ones that match
   var imgPath = $(this).attr('href');
});

// But the variable links is a reference to all the links.
```

Note that you don't have to call each to call a method on all elements of a jQuery object. That's part of what it does. If you are calling a getter, jQuery will return the value for the first one only.